# Child is not a function | Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to render data from realtime firebase in react.

In the console, I am getting the error that

> data.component.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: *firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.default.child is not a function

pointing to the line
`Database.child("L1").on("value", (snapshot) => {` of the below code.

Any thoughts on how I can rectify?

Below is a copy of my code

```
const Data = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState ({});
    useEffect (() => {
        Database.child("L1").on("value", (snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
                setData({ ...snapshot.val() });
            } else {
                setData({});
            }
            });

        return () => {
            setData ({});

        };
    }, []);
    return (
        <div style={{marginTop: "100px"}}>
           
                <table className="styled-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style={{textAlign: "center"}}> L4 </th>
                            <th style={{textAlign: "center"}}> L4 </th>
                         
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {Object.keys(data).map((id, index) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={id}>
                                <th scope="row">{index +1}</th>
                                <td>{data[id].result_1}</td>
                                <td>{data[id].result_2}</td>
                                <td>{data[id].result_3}</td>
                                <td>{data[id].result_4}</td>


                                </tr>
                            )
                        } )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
          
        </div>
    );
};

export default Data
```

Firebase Config

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { Database, getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };


  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const database = getDatabase(app)

  export default Database;
```

Comment: It completely depends on the `Database`. Though you could try `firebase.database().ref("child/path").`

Comment: How is your `Database` variable initialized? And how do you import Firebase?

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Firebase, but with how you are importing the Database object and how your app is being bundled

Comment: Can you share the file where you've initialized Firebase and also Firebase SDK version?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have import `Database` class from Realtime Database SDK. You can just export the `database` instance initialized and then use it.

```
// Firebase config

import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {...};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const database = getDatabase(app)
```

Then use the newer functional syntax instead of older namespaced one. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
// update the path herer
import { database } from '../path/to/firebase-config.js'

const [data, setData] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
  const dbRef = ref(database, 'L1/');
  onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      setData(snapshot.val());
    } else {
      setData({});
    }
  });
}, []);
```

You can use [`exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.datasnapshot.md#datasnapshotexists) instead of checking if snapshot value is null (which is slightly more efficient as mentioned in the documentation)